# How to apply the second fundamental theorem to an itegration with respect to a different variable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I am trying to figure out differentiate $\displaystyle \int \limits_{t_0}^tp(t)q(s)\mathrm ds$ with respect to $t$.

I have tried to use the second fundamental theorem of calculus but get blocked.
How to apply the second fundamental theorem to this kind of problem in general?

Comment: There's a theorem known as the Leibniz integral rule for differentiating under an integral sign that handles this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varphi(t)=\int \limits_{t_0}^tp(t)q(s)ds$. Since $t$ is a constant on the RHS, you have $\varphi(t)=p(t)\int \limits_{t_0}^tq(s)ds$. Now use the product rule and the [FTOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) to differentiatie $\varphi$. (This answer assumes $p$ is differentiable).